# How to execute job on Spring XD with the RESTful api (shell or http)

Tags: spring, rest, spring-xd, spring-batch-admin

I'm working with Spring XD for batch jobs and streams. I have a deployed job in Spring XD with a definition which awaits arguments to be able to run.

a) I'm tried to create a custom UI where end-users can send parameters to the given jobs without them accessing the admin-ui. I'm having trouble with the POST method jobs/execution?jobname={jobName}. It requires a --target (localhost:9393/...) and --data which I've tried to input as {"key":"value"...} or even URL encoded.

```
http post --target http://localhost:9393/jobs/executions?jobname=my-job-name        --data {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"...}
```

b) The batch job doesn't accept arguments from the definition when retrieved with jobParameters().